# friend function

Tags: c++, lookup

What does the following mean (especially the highlighted portion)? Why is the expression 'f(a)' treated as a 'cast expression'?

> C++03 $3.4./3- "The lookup for an unqualified name
>   used as the postfix-expression of a
>   function call is described in 3.4.2.
>   [Note: for purposes of determining
>   (during parsing) whether an expression
>   is a postfix-expression for a function
>   call, the usual name lookup rules
>   apply. The rules in 3.4.2 have no
>   effect on the syntactic interpretation
>   of an expression. For example,

```
typedef int f;
struct A {
friend void f(A &);
operator int();
void g(A a) {
f(a);
}
};
```

**The expression f(a) is a cast-expression equivalent to int(a). Because the expression is not a function call**, the argument-dependent name lookup (3.4.2) does not apply and the friend function f is not found. ]"

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the parser first determines whether the expression before the parentheses is an *id* or a *postfix-expression*. In this case, it sees `f`, and the nearest `f` defined is `typedef int f` - therefore it concludes the expression is interpreted as `int(a)` and no Koenig lookup is performed.

Let's have this code (you an try it online: http://ideone.com/clone/eRKvP)

```
typedef int f;
namespace x {
  struct A {
    friend void f(A &);
    //friend void f(); // # 1
    operator int();
    void g(A a) {
      //void f();  // # 2
      (void)f(a); // # 3
    }
  };
}
```

Had you declared an (unrelated) function `f` visible from `g`, it would be interpreted as a function call and Koenig lookup would find the correct overload (see line `#2`).

The friend declaration of `f` should not apply here, because

> 11.4/1: ... The name of a friend is not in the scope of the class,

However, what's disturbing me, is that uncommenting `#1` makes the compiler (gcc in this case) call `x::f(A&)` too. Not sure why is that. [In Comeau Online compiler, it works as expected (eg. `#1` doesn't influence line `#3`). The latest beta version has problems compiling this code, though.]

PS: As noted by litb, the rules in C++0x are a little different:

> 3.4.2/3:
>
> Let X be the lookup set produced by
>   unqualiﬁed lookup (3.4.1) and let Y be
>   the lookup set produced by argument
>   dependent lookup (deﬁned as follows).
>   If X contains
>
> - a declaration of a class member, or
> - **a block-scope function declaration** that is not a using-declaration, or
> - a declaration that is neither a function or a function template
>
> then Y is empty. Otherwise Y is the
>   set of declarations found in the
>   namespaces associated with the

The bold item will make the compiler only consider `void f()` and fail for too many arguments.

It seems to have been introduced by the resolution of [issue 218](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#218).

Comment: uncommenting #2 would disable koenig lookup according to C++0x rules, though (some compilers use those rules even in C++03 mode). So it would compile as a function call, but as a call to the locally declared function, and would cause an error.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb: Curious to know why friend function isn't found during name lookup even though it is in the lexical scope of the class.

Comment: @Chubsdad: That's because it is not in the scope of the class.

Comment: @Chubsdad "in the lexical scope of the class" is a badly worded rule. It is just intended to mean that the function can find class members with unqualified names. It doesn't mean/it isn't meant to mean that the function name is in the scope of the class.